# Is there a fully enumerated (in a table or on a single page), normative list of "standard" css2 and css3 properties and their values?

Tags: css

This "question" has been asked before I've seen, but none of those existing answers really address the question, nor provide resources that are exhaustive in themselves.  I am looking for a single resource that I can import into code easily, not have to write a web scraper to expand every possible link and then scrape secondary and tertiary pages for property values.

Examples of links that are useless:  (or borderline so)

- http://meiert.com/en/indices/css-properties/
- for other useless links, check the prior questions, my reputation won't let me post more than 2 links as examples.

Almost ok(ish)
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html   (except that it is a small fragment of what is possible with css3 and links elsewhere for other properties, and one has to expand the <...> refs to find the actual values for many properties as well).

Ideally something like in the mozilla headers/code might work, requiring a minimal processing, or just a flat table if someone knows where it is would be great.

Hopefully this doesn't get closed as off topic, because the list of property keys and values is of paramount importance for programmers.  Otherwise how would one know what all the valid values are?  Anyway, I don't think its the kind of question to attract spam, esp as I've done some in depth googling.

This is for inclusion in separate library, not to just write css myself.

Comment: What are you planning to do with this list?

Comment: do you have any code that can post on question content

Comment: Have you thought about looking at the source code for a CSS linter?

Comment: @torazaburo that's a good suggestion, i'll look and see what's there!

Comment: CSS3 is a constantly changing set of goalposts.  the best you can do is look at various snapshots https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS3

Comment: The problem is deciding what to include. When do you consider that a property is standard? When is defined in an editor's draft? In a working draft? In a candidate recommendation? In a recomendation?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something workable, hopefully this helps others too.  Basically the place to look is in the opensource webkit code at the CSSPropertyNames.in and CSSValueKeywords.in files.  I'm looking at version 7601.3.8 on Apple right now.  A user can extract what they need without too much work, though I may just write an easy to use/shareable lib for others.

- http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-7601.3.8/css/CSSPropertyNames.in
- http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-7601.3.8/css/CSSValueKeywords.in

7601.3.8 is up to date as of 2015, according to the changelog.  It may not have absolutely everything, but I think it should work.

Actually the list I included here is not exhaustive either.  The webkit .in files cop out and just list a bunch of values under CSS_PROP_OTHER.

Answer (score 0):

> ...because the list of property keys and values is of paramount importance for programmers. Otherwise how would one know what all the valid values are?

One very easy way to find out the available properties and values is to play with the browser dev tools.

Open the dev tools in your favourite browser. Inspect any element you like from the page you're on, and you should get the HTML shown on the left, with the CSS and other properties of the current element on the right. From here you can explore the available styles, and see their effect in real-time.

The "Computed" styles will show you all the styles that are available and their current settings. The main styles tab will allow you to add new styles or change existing ones. In most browsers, you can use the cursor keys here to explore the values that are available for any given CSS property, and also the properties that are available for the current element. Making changes here will update the page immediately. This is a great way to learn the kinds of things you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, not looking to be told how to press f12 in the browser.  want to incorporate a single list into a library for others to use.